# Extending a simple makefile to support different implicit compiler flags

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have been using a makefile that was fairly straightforward. I defined OBJS with a list of .cc files. I set up dependencies and include flags and appended all of those to $CXXFLAGS. It looks something like this:

```
SRCS = file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cc=.o)
CXXFLAGS=some flags
CXXFLAGS+=some include dirs
$(mylib.so): $OBJS
    $CXX -shared -o $@ $^
```

mylib.so uses the CXXFLAGS (implicitly) and everything builds just fine.

I have recently had the need to have mylib_1.so and mylib_2.so, in addition to mylib.so. Each .so depend on all the same .cc files, but the compiler flags are all different (including include directories).

How do I get it so I can set the compiler flags based on the target .so? The problem that I have is that if I set CXXFLAGS more than once it gets overwritten. It's almost like I need an if/else situation.

I tried doing something like setting three different flags, $CXXFLAGS1, $CXXFLAGS2, $CXXFLAGS3, and using those in the line

```
$(mylib1.so): $OBJS
    $CXX $(CXXFLAGS1) -shared -o $@ $^
```

but that does not work.

How do I accomplish what I am trying to do? Is it better to have 3 separate makefiles? I did find a way to get it to work. I can stop using $OBJS and spell out the flags explicitly for each source file but this seems like a horrible idea in terms of scaling to size.

Comment: I should note that at any given build, only one of the three .so's will be created. I will not need to build all 3 at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CXXFLAGS1 in your example is only used at the stage of creating the .so file, *not* for compilation of the actual C++ sources (which is what you are trying to do, I assume).

To achieve the above, consider making the Makefile invoke itself 3 times for 3 different targets and pass CXXFLAGS (with different values) as part of MAKEFLAGS or in the command line.

**Update:** here's an example

```
all:  build-lib1 build-lib2 build-lib3

build-lib1:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS1)" lib1.so

build-lib2:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS2)" lib2.so

build-lib3:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS3)" lib3.so

$(lib1.so): $OBJS
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $^

etc...
```

Comment: my goal is to avoid setting the flags outside

Comment: The flags would not be set outside - they will be inside your Makefile, but this Makefile will invoke make on itself effectively passing CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS1)" on the command line of that invocation.

Comment: ohhh, I think I see what you are saying. If I change $CXX $(CXXFLAGS1) -shared -o $@ $^ to $CXX CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS1)" -shared -o $@ $^ it should work?

Comment: No, this is not what I said. What I meant is: you have a top-level target that invokes 3 lower-level targets, e.g. 'build-lib1', 'build-lib2' and 'build-lib3.' Target 'build-lib1' is phony and it's commaind is: $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS1)" lib1.so. Same for 2 other targets...

Comment: That works! But I realized my requirement was not totally clear. I want different object files based on the build (build-lib1, build-lib2, etc). So I am changing OBJS = $(SRCS:.cc=.o) --> OBJS1 = $(SRCS:.cc=1.o), OBJS2=$(SRCS:.cc=2.o).... However, I am still using the same source files (file1.cc, file2.cc, etc). How can I get the different object file names, based on which build I pick, to all look at the same source files? make is complaining that it can't find file11.cc which makes sense b/c of some implicit rule?

Comment: FYI - I needed to use the -$(MAKEFLAGS) in order for this to work. This did solve the problem. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

Makefiles can have [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html). Something like:

```
$(mylib1.so): CXXFLAGS += -lib1flags
$(mylib2.so): CXXFLAGS += -lib2flags
$(mylib3.so): CXXFLAGS += -lib3flags
```

According to the documentation, the flags will propagate to prerequisite targets.

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when
>   you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in
>   effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their
>   prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable
>   with their own target-specific variable value). So, for example, a
>   statement like this:
>
> ```
>  prog : CFLAGS = -g
>  prog : prog.o foo.o bar.o
> ```
>
> will set CFLAGS to ‘-g’ in the recipe for prog, but it will also set
>   CFLAGS to ‘-g’ in the recipes that create prog.o, foo.o, and bar.o,
>   and any recipes which create their prerequisites.

Comment: But the same `.o` files need to take different `CXXFLAGS` depending on which final target is being built.

Comment: Does that mean I can do something like: $(mylib.so): $OBJS CXXFLAGS += -lib1flags ?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a recursive call to make.  I would use two makefiles:

In `Makefile`:

```
all: mylib1.so mylib2.so

SRCS := file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc

mylib1.so: $(SRCS)
    test -d mylib1 || mkdir mylib1
    $(MAKE) -f ../lib.mak -C mylib1 TARGET=mylib1.so CXXFLAGS=-DMYLIB=1
    cp mylib1/mylib1.so mylib1.so

mylib2.so: $(SRCS)
    test -d mylib2 || mkdir mylib2
    $(MAKE) -f ../lib.mak -C mylib2 TARGET=mylib2.so CXXFLAGS=-DMYLIB=2
    cp mylib2/mylib2.so mylib2.so
```

In `lib.mak`, in the same directory:

```
VPATH = ..

SRCS := file1.cc file2.cc file3.cc
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cc=.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $^
```

The second makefile actually builds the library, but only uses one set of `CXXFLAGS`.  The primary makefile calls the first makefile for each version with separate `CXXFLAGS` and in a separate directory.  The `VPATH` makes it easier to compile source files that aren't in the same directory.

I tested this setup with a dry run,

```
test -d mylib1 || mkdir mylib1
make -f ../lib.mak -C mylib1 TARGET=mylib1.so CXXFLAGS=-DMYLIB=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/depp/Maketest2/mylib1'
g++ -DMYLIB=1   -c -o file1.o ../file1.cc
g++ -DMYLIB=1   -c -o file2.o ../file2.cc
g++ -DMYLIB=1   -c -o file3.o ../file3.cc
g++ -shared -o mylib1.so file1.o file2.o file3.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/depp/Maketest2/mylib1'
cp mylib1/mylib1.so mylib1.so
test -d mylib2 || mkdir mylib2
make -f ../lib.mak -C mylib2 TARGET=mylib2.so CXXFLAGS=-DMYLIB=2
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/depp/Maketest2/mylib2'
g++ -DMYLIB=2   -c -o file1.o ../file1.cc
g++ -DMYLIB=2   -c -o file2.o ../file2.cc
g++ -DMYLIB=2   -c -o file3.o ../file3.cc
g++ -shared -o mylib2.so file1.o file2.o file3.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/depp/Maketest2/mylib2'
cp mylib2/mylib2.so mylib2.so
```

Comment: would you still do it this way if my requirement is that I only want to build one of the .so's at any given time? I will either call make mylib1.so or make mylib2.so..etc.

Comment: @user1054424: Yes, that will work just fine.  Both `mylib1.so` and `mylib2.so` are targets in the main makefile, so you can make one or the other normally.

Comment: Does this mean each time I add a new source file I need to add it to lib.mak and Makefile?

Comment: @user1054424: You can do it that way.  Or you can put the variable definition in a separate makefile, and `include` that separate makefile from the other two makefiles.  Or you can just use `SRCS := $(wildcard *.cc)`, if you're okay with that.  Or you could even completely eliminate it from the primary makefile.  Lots of options.

Comment: is there a way to accomplish this from within just one makefile? that would be ideal if possible..

Comment: @user1054424: Why would that be ideal?  Could you explain what the purpose of only having one Makefile would be?  (I can help if you explain why.)

Comment: @user1054424: The other alternatives I can see here are (1) use SCons, Jam, or CMake (2) generate the makefile from a script (3) type out the dependency for each object file.  You can see why I thought two makefiles would be the simplest solution.  It sounds like you wish Make were a more sophisticated program.  We all do, but wishing doesn't get the job done.  You could also roll both makefiles into one and use conditionals, but that's a bit of a hack and I don't recommend it.  As always, lots of options.

Comment: I only called it ideal b/c I believed it could be done in one Makefile. I also like to use the Makefile example I posted as a template for other projects, but this paradigm will stray from that, just a bit. If this is truly the best way to do it, I will do it this way.

Comment: @user1054424: For projects with any reasonable level of complexity, makefile maintenance is a job in itself.  Recursive use of make and scripts that generate makefiles are relatively common tricks just to make it through the day.  It's a nice tool but very primitive.